# SVG text border color not matching

Tags: html, svg, fabricjs

When inspecting an black SVG text element through chrome web tools, there's few border pixels that have random colors different than the fill color. That's causing issues when printing from my site.

https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/tryit.asp?filename=trysvg_text

Inspect the generated "I Love SVG!" text you'll see pixels that aren't filled with the same color.

Comment: That'll be antialiasing.

Comment: @mugsexpress This might be helpful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpixel_rendering